# Why does this JQuery split() not work?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I wanna deal with the data respectively. The data has been brought by ajax and can be correctly shown by the first alert(). However, the second alert() does not work at all.

```
 $.ajax({
       type:"get", 
    url:"Ajax_UserConfirmation.action", 
    dataType:"json", 
    success:function(value){
    alert(value);
    alert(value.split(','));
```

the value:   t33,t34

Comment: [`.split()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split) is a method of string values. However, `value` is likely an `Array`, with little need to split. You can check that with `console.log(value);`, `typeof value === 'object'` or `Array.isArray(value)`.

Comment: Use the debugger, or the console.log to find out what `value` actually is.  Since your dataType is `json` it is unlikely that you are getting a string value back.

Comment: Btw, `split` is a native `JS` function (jQuery has nothing to do with it) which splits a `String` and returns an `Array` Check using `console.log(value)`.

Comment: That should not be possible. JSON is either an array or an object. Neither of them have `split`. I don't believe that the alert shows that. This question is dishonest.

Answer (score 0):

split() works on Strings and returns an array, check to see value's type and if it is indeed a String, something like, "t33,t34" or "t33,t34,t35,t36" and you just want to deal with the individual values separated by "," of the String, use the indices of the new array like this:

```
var valueArray = value.split(",")
alert(valueArray[0] + "," + valueArray[1])
```

which is redundant unless the String of values separated by commas is longer and you just want those values, or:

```
alert(valueArray[0])
alert(valueArray[1])
```

or whatever the indices would be, since you are splitting the assumed String by the ',' separator and putting the values into an array.

Answer (score -1):

The split method returns an Array with the values. You can access them in this way:

```
var result = value.split(',');
result[0] is the first position of the array.
result[1] is the second position.
```

Javascript split docs [here](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_split.asp)

If your response ("value") is an Array you don't need to split it.

Tip: Use `console.log` instead of `alert` to debug. 
eg. `console.log(value);`

Comment: Don't see how this explains why it doesn't work in OP's case.